# Using Commit in a SQL Server Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

Currently I am working on a requirement which requires logging of input record into a staging table.

The requirement summery is as below:

- Web Service will send a request which will insert a record into the level 1 staging table (`StagingTable1`).
- A database trigger on `StagingTable1` will process the validity of the record and raise an error
- This error message gets acknowledged as Web Service response to other end system.

My challenge is to track these failed records in another staging table `StagingTable2`. But `RAISERROR` in a trigger is causing the entire transaction to rollback.

How this can be achieved?

Note: I tried temporary tables but it does not work. `Pragma_autonomuos` transactions are not possible in SQL Server as far as I know.

Comment: It is hard to answer specifically without specifics.  Share minimal code that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: Vote [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/296870/add-support-for-autonomous-transactions) to implement the issue! (you may use a real RDBMS)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the trigger put the record into the `StagingTable2` - or not, so the absence of it will indicate an unsuccessful validation. You can even put error descriptions, along with row' key, into some other table, so that you will always know which ones failed to pass.

Or you can use Service Broker for that, if your servers are far enough away from each other.